# Error: Looks like you are rendering without using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

when I open my unity webGL build, i will receive the following error:

> "Looks like you are rendering without using requestAnimationFrame for
>   the main loop. You should use 0 for the frame rate in
>   emscripten_set_main_loop in order to use requestAnimationFrame, as
>   that can greatly improve your frame rates!"

the game does not crash but it affects so much the quality of the game.

Anybody can help to resolve this?

Comment: Apologies, but I am not understanding. The message seems to be telling you exactly what it needs in order to be suppressed. Are you not wishing to set the frame rate to 0 in your emscripten_set_main_loop?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did not set anything, the build is done using unity3D and I'm not sure where should I set the emscripten_set_main_loop to 0. I'm just a beginner in this. thanks

Comment: Are you setting `Application.targetFrameRate` anywhere in your code?